# How to insert in php fo array of string value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I have an array

```
   Array(  
         [0] => Column 1, Column 2 ,Column 3,Column 4,Column 5,Column 6
         [1] => 19506,7254,321878,8,1,60 
         [2] => 187486,685,377,3,0,0 
         [3] => 187498,682285,3354,45,1,400 
         [4] => 18498,681285,38959,2,0,0 
      )
```

store into a mysql table using a loop or any other solutions
how to insert in database
I have exact same columns in a table

Comment: Could you please add more information about your connection method and what you have tried so far.

Comment: How did this array come about? Seems like a really weird way to be handling data.

Answer (score 3):

Use below snippet to convert it into array to save into database,

```
// replace spaces with "" and explode with comma
$keys = explode(",", str_replace(" ","",$arr[0]));
array_shift($arr); // remove first index
$arr = array_map(function($a) use($keys){
    // first value as keys and rest array values exploding and combining as key value pair
    return array_combine($keys, explode(",",$a));
}, $arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cp2s7)

Code to create an insert query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (".implode(",",$keys).") VALUES ";
foreach($arr as $data){
    $sql .= "(".implode(",",$data)."),";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");
echo $sql;
```

**Output**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6)  
VALUES (19506,7254,321878,8,1,60),(187486,685,377,3,0,0), 
(187498,682285,3354,45,1,400),(18498,681285,38959,2,0,0)
```